# how to change shortkeys for switching between VT and X?

Tags: terminal, tty

I am using an software which has a TUI and I would like to use it on a virtual terminal. The software uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> shortkeys to do perform some tasks. So I need to either disable, or change the predefined behaviour of those key combination on my linux machine (which currently switches between virtual terminals and X session)

So how can I change <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> shortkey ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Linux (not [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vt&sektion=4)...).

This should disable the special features on Alt+Left or Alt+Right, leaving only Alt+Fn keys working to change console. It should be run on a console and requires root to load a new keymap:

```
dumpkeys > backup-keymap
dumpkeys | sed 's/Decr_Console/Left/g;s/Incr_Console/Right/g' | loadkeys
```

To revert, use `loadkeys < backup-keymap`, or restart some system keyboard configuration tool.

I don't know how to integrate this correctly at boot in a keymap. It might depend on Distribution (and if using systemd ...)

The file [`/etc/console-setup/remap.inc`](https://sources.debian.org/src/console-setup/1.164/Keyboard/remap.inc/) on Debian might give more clues on how to properly override the keyboard instead of those low level commands, on Debian.